# How to work with multiple data sources within a working directory/RProject in RStudio

Tags: r, filepath, working-directory

I am trying to get to grips with the idea that you shouldn't change the working directory and also good transferable/transparant working practices mean it's worth using the RProjects option. However, this has caused me an issue when I have to draw upon different datasets within a single project. I am currently struggling to map a dataset from a file that is within a subfile of my working directory.

I use the code `import <- list.files( pattern = ".csv", recursive = TRUE) %>% map_df(~read_csv(.,col_types = cols(.default = 'd', 'UTCDateTime' = 'c', 'mac_address' = 'c', 'firmware_ver' = 'c', 'hardware' = 'c')))`  that will work if i have my files stored in the working directory.

To keep my project file manageable and due to having to work with multiple sets of .csv files, I cannot have them all in the working directory.

If I then specify the path I want by using `path = 'insert absolute/relative path here'` within the list.files I get an error:

`'file1/20190913.csv' does not exist in the current working directory ('insert working directory here').`

Any advice on working within files would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you! reading the documentation again now makes sense that this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `list.files` statement returns the names of the files found in the `path` you give, e.g. `myfile.csv`, and `read_csv` searches these files in the current directory, where they are not.

If you add the option `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files`, it will return the absolute paths to the files, and `read_csv` will find them.